# Ambiguos JAVA Interfaces

Tags: error-handling

How can you define the classes/interfaces Adult, Student and Engineer so that the next sequence to give compilation error only where specified?

```
class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
Adult a = new Student(); //without giving compilation error
Adult b = new Engineer();//without giving compilation error
a.explorare(); //without giving compilation error
b.explorare(); //without giving compilation error
a.afisare(); //without giving compilation error
b.afisare(); //compilation error
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, if `a.afisare()` compiles then so should `b.afisare()`.

Comment: +1 The compiler sees two instances of `Adult`, so they would have exactly the same methods/properties available.

Comment: With another interface ,it doesn t matter how you define these.